# "SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax" when trying to run a .py script from IDLE in Command Prompt

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-idle

I just started learning python. I created a simple .py file using the IDLE editor and I am trying to run it from the command prompt. However, every time it keeps giving me the "SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax" message.

This is how the .py file looks when opened with notepad:

```
 Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

 >>> import sys

 >>> print(sys.platform)

 win32

 >>> x="Spam!"

 >>> print(x*8)

 Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!Spam!

 >>> print(2**100)

 1267650600228229401496703205376

 >>>
```

And this is what I type in the cmd:

```
 C:\code\script1.py
```

Assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: That's not a py file at all. That's a copy of a shell session. What tutorial told you to put that in a file?

Comment: I ran the code in IDLE then saved it as a .py file. That isnt a script?

Comment: No not at all. You can surely see it has many things that are not Python code: those first two introduction lines, the >>> prompts, and your own output from your print statements. What would they be doing in a script?

Comment: Is there a way to get the IDLE editor to only save the code?

Comment: See my \[EDIT\].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not a Python program, it's the log of an interactive (command prompt) session.

Instead, try entering the following in any text editor (e.g. notepad, notepad++), save it as C:\code\script2.py and then run it as you did:

```
import sys

print(sys.platform)

x="Spam!"
print(x*8)

print(2**100)
```

[EDIT]
If you want to use Idle for this, click [File][New] to create a Python source code file, type in the above, save it and then run it as you did.

[EDIT2]
Idle is and example of an Interactive Development Environment (IDE). Since you're new to programming: IDE's tend to obscure what's going on, although Idle isn't a severe case of this. So using a separate editor and running from the command line as you did is actually a good way to familiarize yourself with what's going on under the hood. This will pay off in many ways in the long run.

Comment: Is there a way to get the IDLE editor to only save the code?

Comment: See my \[EDIT\] on how to use Idle for this.

Answer (score 0):

As said before; This is not a python file...

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

That's the shell (which you get if you just type: `python`) where you can type commands like:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
    print(x)
```

and this will instantly execute...

What you need to to is go on and create a `script.py` file, write your stuff in there and then execute it as: `python script.py`

Greeting Elias