# Any way to fix syntax error on import in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Completely new to programming here. A couple of issues that I believe are related to one another:

write a simple code like

```
def converttocelsius(f)
    return ((f-32)*(5/9))
```

Save it as temp.py in lib folder. Open it, try to edit it but it acts like a text file instead (but the python colorization is still there). Try to import it in a new IDLE session and get this syntax error.

'''

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import temp.py
      File "C:\Python34\lib\temp.py", line 1
        Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on 
            win32
         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

'''

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you copied a whole interpreter session transcript into `temp.py`, including the Python startup header and possibly the `>>>` and `...` prompts. That stuff doesn't go in a `.py` file.

Comment: Also, 3.4.3 is pretty outdated.

Comment: How would i get rid of the extra fluff then? Seems like I should be writing functions in a different environment completely to be able to import in other shells.

Comment: You're not supposed to write modules in an interactive session.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax when trying to run a .py script in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289216/syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-when-trying-to-run-a-py-script-in-command-prompt)

Comment: a little bit. i got a different error initially (forgot colon after closing parentheses), and then more of the same after.

Import Error:
No module named 'temp.py' ; 'temp' is not a package

Comment: Then this post now has become *very* unclear, since what you are now describing is different from what is posted in the Question body.

Comment: After trying out some of the methods in the other linked post, I was able to get it imported! (im ecstatic, honestly) Now the only issue is that the function wont work unless I use 
''' from temp import converttocelsius'''

and for the record, if I try to import temp.py (instead of just 'temp'), it doesn't recognize it and gives me the error 

'''ImportError: No module named 'temp.py'; 'temp' is not a package'''

I'll take this as a win.
All in all this has been extremely helpful in terms of figuring how and where to look for help and answers. Thank you Gino!